# Jtable formato moeda

Tags: java, swing, jtable, formatação

Estou fazendo um CellRender com formato de moeda. eu coloquei 13 colunas em uma jtable, uma tem as receitas (Salário, 13º salário, Hora extra).. e outas 12 com os meses. a cada mês a pessoa vai digitar essas informações e depois vou acrescentar uma outra jtable com as despesas. alguém tem um exemplo de CellRender para essa necessidade?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei esse exemplo que me serve bem, mas não to conseguindo usa-lo para um jframe e um defaulttablemode que puxo informações do banco.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class EditorTest {

    private JScrollPane getTableComponent() {
        String[] colNames = {
            "Preço", "Número"
        };
        final Object[][] data = {
            {new Double(2), Double.valueOf(12.21)},
            {Double.valueOf(12.21), Double.valueOf(12.21)},
            {Double.valueOf(12.21), Double.valueOf(12.21)},
            {Double.valueOf(12.21), Double.valueOf(12.21)}
        };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames) {
            public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
                return data[0][col].getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        TableColumnModel colModel = table.getColumnModel();
        //colunas
        colModel.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new DoubleRenderer());
        colModel.getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new DoubleRenderer());
        table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        Dimension d = table.getPreferredSize();
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(d);
        return new JScrollPane(table);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new EditorTest().getTableComponent());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocation(100, 100);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class DoubleRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    NumberFormat numeroFormatado = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    public DoubleRenderer() {
        setHorizontalAlignment(RIGHT);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                hasFocus, row, column);
        setText(numeroFormatado.format(((Double) value).doubleValue()));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja a edição recente na resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O exemplo abaixo retirado do [SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673276/5524514) pode servir:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
public class CurrencyTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    private static final NumberFormat FORMAT = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    @Override
    public final Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        final Component result = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value instanceof Number) {
            setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
            setText(FORMAT.format(value));
        } else {
            setText("");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Para exibição correta, você precisa também definir o tipo de dado nessa coluna no `TableModel`. Se estiver usando ponto flutuante, basta retornar o tipo equivalente:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return columnIndex == 0 ? Double.class : super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
}
```

Veja funcionando corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O método `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()` retornará a formatação da moeda corrente do local informado pelo sistema e aplicará ao campo sempre que for passado um valor numérico para a coluna.

Se deseja restringir a formatação a uma determinada moeda independente do local do sistema de quem executa a aplicação, é necessário informar o local através de outro método homônimo:

```
private static final NumberFormat brazilianFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
```

Da forma acima, sempre aplicará o formato da moeda brasileira. Veja uma demonstração disso no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/KNZ0M7), cujo formato recuperado é o da moeda estadunidense.

Comment: perfeito, deu tudo certo!

Comment: Eita rapaz bom, ficou massa :D +1