# Jtable com valor monetário em uma unica coluna

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Buscando implementar uma formatação de valor monetário em uma jtable, tentei usar a pergunta do [Rafael Chaves](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236991/jtable-formato-moeda) como base e consegui fazer o codigo abaixo.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class PrincipalTabelaValor extends JFrame {

    private final JTable table;
    private final int id1 = 1;
    private final int id2 = 2;
    private final int id3 = 3;
    private final double qtd1 = 10.10;
    private final double qtd2 = 9.20;
    private final double qtd3 = 8.30;
    private final double vl1 = 5.50;
    private final double vl2 = 6.51;
    private final double vl3 = 7.52;

    public PrincipalTabelaValor() {
        super("Tabela de Cadastro de Produtos");

        // constructs the table
        String[] columnNames = new String[]{"ID", "Descrição", "quantidade", "Preço"};
        Object[][] rowData = new Object[][]{
            {id1, "TOMATE", qtd1, vl1},
            {id2, "BANANA", qtd2, vl2},
            {id3, "UVA", qtd3, vl3}
        };

        table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new CONTabelaProduto());

        add(new JScrollPane(table));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(640, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

//  CONTROLA A TABELA
    public class CONTabelaProduto extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private final NumberFormat FORMAT = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jtable, Object conteudo, boolean linhaSelecionada, boolean hasFocus, int linha, int coluna) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jtable, conteudo, linhaSelecionada, hasFocus, linha, coluna);

            if (linha % 2 == 0) {
                setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 255, 80));
            } else {
                setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 255, 20));
            }

            if (linhaSelecionada) {
                setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 102, 100));
            }

            if (conteudo instanceof Double) {
                setText(FORMAT.format(conteudo));
            }

            jtable.setRowHeight(25);
            jtable.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 0, 14));
            jtable.setOpaque(false);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PrincipalTabelaValor().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Jtable]

Como podem ver, a formatação foi atribuída também na coluna "quantidade", e eu gostaria de atribuir essa formatação apenas na coluna "preço".

Tentei seguir o exemplo do [Rob Camick](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) criando a class abaixo.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class NumberRenderer extends FormatRenderer {

    public NumberRenderer(NumberFormat formatter) {
        super(formatter);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    }

    public static NumberRenderer getCurrencyRenderer() {
        return new NumberRenderer(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());
    }
}
```

E chamando a class com

```
jtable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(NumberRenderer.getCurrencyRenderer());
```

Mas acaba sobrescrevendo o background definido.

[image: jtable]

Gostaria de verificar se existe uma forma de atribuir esse tipo de formatação sem que sobrescreva a definição de background.

Comment: Sua tabela so tem 4 colunas?

Comment: A tabela original tem bem mais colunas, criei esse código apenas para demonstrar de for simples o dilema que estava passando.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger concordo, esse trecho não haveria necessidade de estar ai, poderia ser definido direto na classe principal, junto com a propria tabela.

Comment: Criei assim porque minha `DefaultTableCellRenderer` fica em uma class separada, mas obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples neste código é, dentro do seu `DefaultTableCellRenderer` pegar o índice da coluna `preço` ao invés do tipo da coluna, e quando o indice for o mesmo, aplicar a formatação:

```
if (coluna == 3) {
    setText(FORMAT.format(conteudo));
}
```

ou se a coluna preço for sempre a última, independente da quantidade de colunas:

```
if (coluna == (jtable.getColumnCount()-1)) {
    setText(FORMAT.format(conteudo));
}
```